# JUnit throws java.lang.NullPointerException when testing with JPA

Tags: jpa, junit

I'm trying to run a JUnit test for my simple java program that uses JPA and I always get the following error:

```
Testcase: testGetSummary(logic.rezepteVerwaltenTest):   Caused an ERROR
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at logic.rezepteVerwalten.getSummary(rezepteVerwalten.java:41)
    at logic.rezepteVerwaltenTest.testGetSummary(rezepteVerwaltenTest.java:56)
```

I have two questions:

- where lies the problem? (obvious question, wasn't it :-))
- how do I get a more detailed stack trace from the JUnit test

BTW: it works very well if I call the methods via JSF.

I would appreciate any help! Thank you!

The JUnit Test:

```
package logic;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.*;
import javax.ejb.EJB;

public class rezepteVerwaltenTest {


@EJB
private rezepteVerwalten rezepte = new rezepteVerwalten();



public rezepteVerwaltenTest() {
}

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() {


}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownClass() {
}

@Before
public void setUp() {

}

@After
public void tearDown() {

}

/**
 * Test of getSummary method, of class rezepteVerwalten.
 */
@Test
public void testGetSummary() {
    System.out.println("getSummary");
    rezepte.getSummary();

    assert(true);
}
}
```

The class:

```
package logic;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import entity.rezepte;
import facades.*;
import helper.Calculate;
import interfaces.Logger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import logic.RezepteLogger;

@ManagedBean(name = "rezepteVerwalten")
@RequestScoped
public class rezepteVerwalten {

    @EJB
    private rezepteFacade rezepteFacade;
    @EJB
    private Logger logger;

    private String name;
    private String zubereitung;
    private String summary;


    public String getSummary() {
        List<rezepte> rezepte = rezepteFacade.findAll();
        List<String> rez = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i<rezepte.size();i++) {
            String output = rezepte.get(i).toString()+" "+ rezepte.get(i).getRezeptName()+": "+rezepte.get(i).getRezeptZubereitung();      
            rez.add(output);
        }
        return rez.toString();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getZubereitung() {
        return zubereitung;
    }

    public void setZubereitung(String zubereitung) {
        this.zubereitung = zubereitung;
    }


    public void rezepteVerwalten() {
        this.name ="";
        this.zubereitung="";
    }

    public void rezepteVerwalten(String name, String zubereitung) {
        this.name = name;
        this.zubereitung = zubereitung;
    }

    public String createRezept() {


          rezepte rezept = new rezepte();

          rezept.setRezeptName(name);
          rezept.setRezeptZubereitung(zubereitung);

          rezepteFacade.create(rezept);

          return "theend";
    }

    public void listRezepte() {


        List<rezepte> rezepte = rezepteFacade.findAll();
        List<String> rez = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i<rezepte.size();i++) {
            String output = rezepte.get(i).toString()+" "+ rezepte.get(i).getRezeptName()+": "+rezepte.get(i).getRezeptZubereitung();

            rez.add(output);

            logger.logIt(output);
            logger.logIt(Calculate.calculateMenge(2, i+1, 5).toString());

        }

    }


}
```

The entity:

```
package entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity
public class rezepte implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String rezeptName;
    private String rezeptZubereitung;


    public String getRezeptName() {
        return rezeptName;
    }

    public void setRezeptName(String rezeptName) {
        this.rezeptName = rezeptName;
    }

    public String getRezeptZubereitung() {
        return rezeptZubereitung;
    }

    public void setRezeptZubereitung(String rezeptZubereitung) {
        this.rezeptZubereitung = rezeptZubereitung;
    }



    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof rezepte)) {
            return false;
        }
        rezepte other = (rezepte) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entity.rezepte[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

And the facades:

```
package facades;

import entity.rezepte;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;


@Stateless
public class rezepteFacade extends AbstractFacade<rezepte> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "RezeptePU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public rezepteFacade() {
        super(rezepte.class);
    }

}


package facades;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;


public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {
    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    public void create(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }

    public void edit(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }

    public void remove(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
    }

    public T find(Object id) {
        return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }

    public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0]);
        q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
        return q.getResultList();
    }

    public int count() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
        cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
    }

}
```

Comment: A lot of the Java EE stuff like EJB injection only works when run within an Java Application Server. JUnit runs normally standalone. It should be possible to do this using an embedded container. This tutorial for netbeans illustrates that http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/javaee-entapp-junit.html however I have tried that tutorial yesterday and haven't got it to work yet.

Comment: Thanks, this helped! It was my fault of thinking that the entity manager could also be simulated by JUnit. I mocked the EM and now my test works fine.